# React Router v6: Unable to Access Routes Deployed on Vercel

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router-dom, vercel

**What version of React Router are you using?**
I am using React Router version 6.22.3.

**Steps to Reproduce:**
I have the following code setup for routing:

```js
import * as React from 'react'
import ReactDom from 'react-dom/client'
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom'

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <div> welcome </div>,
  },
  {
    path: 'test',
    element: <div> test </div>
  }
])

ReactDom.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <RouterProvider router={router} />
  </React.StrictMode>
)
```

**Expected Behavior:**
able to access /test route.

**Actual Behavior:**
When deployed on Vercel, I encounter a 404 error when trying to access the /test route. Here's the deployed link for reference: [Vercel Deployment](https://react-router-v6-fyet8yqu3-jadesnowman.vercel.app/test)

Comment: I don't know what is going on with your link, but it seems I get redirected to a Vercel page that wants me to create an account or log in. Have you correctly deployed your app? Is your deployed app setup/configured for client-side routing? Check the CRA deployment docs for [Vercel](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#vercel) to see what may need to be setup. The basic gist is that the server or hosting service needs to be configured to return the root index.html file for all page requests into the app. To be clear, this isn't anything you can fix client-side in your app code.

Comment: Hi @DrewReese thanks for helping, the vercel deployment is no issue, but not sure somehow vercel redirect to register, related your suggestion i tried it on nginx and it works from `try_files $uri $uri/ =404` to `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;`